# Truncating an existing fstream that has been locked by boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, posix, boost-interprocess

What would happen if I **reopen** an `fstream` with data in it using the `std::ios::trunc` flag without closing a process and whilst my process holds a `boost::interprocess::file_lock()`?

Should I expect the OS to maintain my file lock? Or will the OS transparently unregister the lock when the file is closed? Both Windows and POSIX experience would be appreciated.

**edit**

my main goal is to truncate a config file and rewrite it. The secondary purpose of the file is to prevent other equivalent daemons from starting up. So if there is another way using boost or c++ stl to truncate a file without closing it, I'm all ears :D

Comment: Assuming your OS supports file locking at all, your reopen should just fail, unless I misunderstand something somewhere...

Comment: lets assume I am using a modern posix/winapi implementation (say something from the last decade or two ?)

Comment: IIRC POSIX does not do file locking. I think Linux supports it as a nonstandard extension, and I don't think most BSDs support it at all. I could be wrong though.

Comment: does it matter if it is standard or non-standard ? I am sorry I erroneously used the posix tag. lets assume any unix os that is in active development and that calls itself partially posix compliant.

Comment: BSD is under active development and calls itself posix compliant.

Comment: sure, fine, BSD then, I don't care if it's advisory or enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically : reopening a file using `std::fstream::close` followed by `std::fstream::open` will drop the lock transparently, (as tested with linux command `lsof`) after doing this the lock needs to be re-acquired using `boost::interprocess`.

So, as long as you follow the open-file followed by acquire-lock, you should be fine.

You might want to run the same test in windows.